# Can I calculate the cardinality of the _id field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I have multiple Elasticsearch 1.3.2 indices, and I'm using custom document IDs. I want to find the number of distinct IDs across my indices. Some documents have the same ID but are in different indices, so this is different from just counting documents. So I wanted to do a cardinality aggregation on the _id field. So I posted this to http://localhost:9200/*my_indices*/_search:

```
{ "from": 0, "size": 0, "aggregations": { "_count": { "cardinality": { "script": "doc['_id'].value", "lang": "groovy" } } } }
```

But Elasticsearch just sent back this:

```
{ "took": 60, "timed_out": false, "_shards": { "total": 175, "successful": 175, "failed": 0 }, "hits": { "total": 310714, "max_score": 0, "hits": [] }, "aggregations": { "_count": { "value": 0 } }
```

I'm pretty sure there's more than 0 IDs in there! What happened, and is it possible to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_id` field is [not analyzed and not stored, by default](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-id-field.html). And I think it's not stored in `_source`, as well. You can't use it with aggregations as is.

For your indices you need to change that, to have the `_id` indexed:

```
  "_id": {
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  }
```

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it's possible. Is there a way to modify my existing indices to have the _id indexed?

Comment: @InquisitiveIdiot you can, but you have to re-index :(

Comment: What @TheWhiteRabbit said :-).

Answer (score 2):

There's another solution without the need to reindex everything, i.e. use the [`_uid`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-uid-field.html) field instead:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "_count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "_uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```